# failed to run pt-table-checksum

Tags: mysql, perl

OS: suse linux enterprise server 11 sp1
mysql: 5.6.17
perl: 5.10.0
pt-table-checksum: percona-toolkit-2.2.8-1.noarch.rpm

There is an error while I run pt-table-checksum:
06-30T04:27:53 install_driver(mysql) failed: Attempt to reload DBD/mysql.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 16) line 3. at /usr/bin/pt-table-checksum line 1569

I think this should be caused by perl-DBD-mysql.

I have changed version from perl-DBD-mysql-4.008-4.2.x86_64.rpm to perl-DBD-mysql-4.021-27.1.x86_64.rpm. Installation is successful, but the problem is still there.

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: from http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Attempt-to-reload-%25s-aborted. : "You tried to load a file with use or require that failed to compile once already". Does this produce any errors? `perl -e'use DBD::mysql'`

Comment: Thanks snoopy, there is an error while running perl -e'use DBD::mysql':Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-threadmulti/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-th read-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 203.
 at -e line 1
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Comment: Odd, http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/21374384/dir/opensuse/com/perl-DBD-mysql-4.021-27.1.x86_64.rpm.html provides that file. Can you see it on the file-system? `ls -l /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so`

Comment: thanks snoopy, pt-table-checksum is working now. But there is another problem while running pt-table-checksum: pt-table-checksum h='127.0.0.1',u='checksums',p='mycheck654321',P=3306 -d m_xinhui_mall --nocheck-replication-filters --replicate=test.checksums --recursion-method=hosts
Cannot connect to P=3306,h=54.88.81.243,p=...,u=checksums
Diffs cannot be detected because no slaves were found.  Please read the --recursion-method documentation for information.

Comment: but when I run mysql commands: mysql> show processlist\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 18349
   User: slave_backup
   Host: 54.88.81.243:53736
     db: NULL
Command: Binlog Dump
   Time: 1983
  State: Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated
   Info: NULL

Comment: mysql> show slave hosts;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| Server_id | Host         | Port | Master_id | Slave_UUID                           |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|         2 | 54.88.81.243 | 3306 |         1 | fc270fa7-fc12-11e3-ae97-0a5293bda275 |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
they seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above problem since the slave mysql was binded to 127.0.0.1, so I can not access it remotely. the solution is to commit the line in my.cnf: bind-address  = 127.0.0.1.

But there is another error getting while running pt-table-checksum:

Waiting for the --replicate table to replicate to my slave server...
Waiting for the --replicate table to replicate to my slave server ...
Waiting for the --replicate table to replicate to my slave server ...

then nothing return. how to fix this issue?